# Datepicker change date fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm facing this issue where the date change fires twice, the user picks a date and the date would be in the format "`dd-mm-yyyy`" but when the user clicks out the date field or changes the date, it would change to "`YYYY-MM-DD`" (I need it to be in this format at submission)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**Relevant Code:**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: DateOfBirth" value="" required="" name="DateOfBirth" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" data-val-required="Date of Birth is required." data-val="true" autocomplete="off"class="form-control input-sm datepicker" aria-required="true" onkeydown="return false"  />

<script>
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            startView: "decade",
            minViewMode: "days",
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            endDate : '0'
        });

    $('#DateOfBirth').change(function ()
    {
        var date = $(this).val();
        if (date != null && date != "")
        {
            var dateArray = date.split('/');
            if (dateArray.length === 3)
            {
                myModel.DateOfBirth(dateArray[2] + "-" + dateArray[1] + "-" + dateArray[0]);
            }
        }
        $(this).valid();  
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  managed to fix it by using jquery-ui,

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: DateOfBirth" value="" required="" name="DateOfBirth" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" data-val-required="Date of Birth is required." data-val="true" autocomplete="off"class="form-control input-sm datepicker" aria-required="true" onkeydown="return false"  />

<input type="hidden" id="BirthDate" value="" data-bind="value: DateOfBirth" />

<script>
        $(function () {

            $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                altField: "#BirthDate",
                altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
            });

        $('#DateOfBirth').change(function () {
            var date = $("#BirthDate").val();
            if (date != null && date != "") {
                myModel.DateOfBirth(date);
            }
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`myModel` is not defined anywhere.

You could do it like this:

```
    $('#DateOfBirth').change(function() {
      var date = $(this).val();
      if (date != null && date != "") {
        var dateArray = date.split('/');
        if (dateArray.length === 3) {
          $('#DateOfBirth').val(dateArray[2] + "-" + dateArray[1] + "-" + dateArray[0]);
        }
      }
      $(this).valid();
    });
```

But again you will see just `YYYY-MM-DD` format in input. Because it is updated on change and it is changing whenever you choose date so initial format is always overwritten.

You can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/vo7k676n/

You could do that format change serverside or on form submit instead of on input change.